# saving strings that are 'connected' and reading them and their 'connected'

Tags: delphi, save

This is something I am not at all familiar with.

I want to try to make a simple form with 4 edit boxes, 2 at the top, 2 at the bottom, and a button. Basically what I want to do is type a couple of things in the top two boxes that are related to each other.

When I have them both filled in I click on the button and it saves this information in a database, preferable an external file (doesn't have to be text, I think it would be better if not). So I can do that a couple of times. Saving from the edit fields into a database.

Then when I type one of the words saved in one of the edit fields at the bottom it automatically types the other word in the last edit field. The form should remember to connect to the database every time it's opened so that when I open it another time I can still work the edit fields.

Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

Comment: I think you need to narrow down your question, in its current form it reads like "how do I program", and I'm not sure SO is the best medium for general teaching. What specifically has you stumped in this project right now, if you can narrow it down to a single question to begin with, that would probably give you something to start with.

Comment: Question is too broad, so I've voted to close it. Please ask more specific questions. Among the things you seem to want to know are how to connect to a database and how to look something up in a database. Apparently, you already know how to store things in a database (although I'm not sure how, since you don't know how to connect to it yet). Ask about each of those things separately. Be sure to mention what database you're using. (If you don't know that, then ask for advice on choosing a database, too.) Be sure to search prior questions before asking new ones.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is known as a dictionary, if I understand you correctly.  In other languages it is known as an associative array or sometimes a hash.

You are going to want a modern version of Delphi, I'd guess 2010 or XE.  If you can't access those then you'd need a 3rd party library, or a home grown based off a `TStringList`. In fact `TStringList` can operate in a dictionary like mode but it's a bit clunky.

You declare the dictionary as follows:

```
dict: TDictionary<string,string>;
```

You can add do it as follows:

```
dict.Add(box1.Text, box2.Text);
```

The first parameter is the key. The second is the value. Think of this as an array but indexed with a string rather than an integer.

If you want to recover a value then you use:

```
dict[key];
```

In your case you would write:

```
box4.Text := dict[box3.Text];
```

If you want to save to a file then you would iterate over the dict:

```
var
  item: TPair<string,string>;
...
for item in dict do
  AddToTextFile(item.Key, item.Value);
```

I've ignored all error handling issues, dealing with adding keys that already exist, asking for keys that are not in the dict, and so on. But this should give you a flavour.

I'd recommend reading up on associative arrays if you aren't already familiar with them. I'm sure there will be a page on Wikipedia and you would do worse than read an tutorial on Python which is sure to cover them – the issues are really the same no matter what language you consider.

Comment: As a curiosity, I thought one used the EM dash in English, not the EN dash? As a UK citizen, what is your experience in this matter?

Comment: @Andreas em-dash is too long for that context, it's en-dash that you want, ALT+0150!

Comment: @David: OK. In Sweden we only use EN, so maybe EM is a US thing.

Comment: @Andreas I mean, I think the grammar police would do me for using en-dash there, but I prefer it!!

Comment: @David: Yes, I would also guess that, for I have always thought one does use EM in English (in contrast to the Swedish rules). Still, I am glad you don't use the hyphen-minus as most people do...

Comment: @Andreas I hate hypen there too. I'm so glad for Unicode Delphi which means I can now safely use en-dash in my app's error messages!

Comment: Me too. Actually, as a mathematician, I also use U+2212 MINUS SIGN (−) a lot, too.

Comment: @Andreas now that's verging on OCD! Actually, as a mathematician you should be setting it in LaTeX, using the plain minus sign and letting Donald and Leslie do the rest for you!! I used to be a mathematician too!

Comment: (Well, there is HTML, Delphi code etc. where TeX isn't an option...)

Comment: @ David Heffernan -  thx, thats actually very interesting. What do you recomend is you want 4 column of information, 2 string 2 integer?

Comment: I'm just thinking ahead, possible expanding the database?

Comment: you thinking of one key and three values? That's easy using generics: TDictionary<string, TMyRecord>

Comment: More like 2 keys and each have two pieces of information. one string and one integer. When I lookup in the the Tdictionary for the string of the first key, i can get the rest of the values as well. but I dont think that is possible in dictionary. So maybe i need a different type of database.

Comment: you need to work out what your question really is!